# How do I rerender a FlatList when a value of an object changes?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-flatlist

The idea is to have a toggle switch that switches from **To Watch** and **Watched** bookings. When I update a movie in the **To Watch** list, I want it to rerender the FlatList without that booking because it's now in the **Watched** list. And so when I press the toggle to see the **Watched** list I would now see the booking there. Same for reverse. This is the code I have:

```
const WatchList = () => {

  const uid = auth.currentUser.uid;
  const docRef = doc(db, 'users', uid);
  const [user, setUser] = useState({});
  const [watched, setWatched] = useState(true);
  const [text, setText] = useState('To watch');
  const [filteredBookings, setFilteredBookings] = useState(bookings);

  const bookingsRef = collection(db, "booking"); // imamo ref ka bazi

  const [bookings, setBookings] = useState({});
   useEffect(() => {
    getUser();
    getBookings();
  },[])

  const getUser = async () => {
    const snap = await getDoc(docRef)
    setUser({user, ...snap.data()})
  }

  const getBookings = async () =>{
    const q = query(bookingsRef, where("users","array-contains",auth.currentUser.uid));
      const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
        const a = [];
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {            
        a.push(doc.data());
      });
      setBookings(querySnapshot.docs);
    });
  }

  const toggleSwitch = () =>{
    if(!watched){
      setFilteredBookings(bookings.filter(function(item){
        return item.data().watched == true;
      }))
      setText('Watched');
    } else {
      setText('To watch');
      setFilteredBookings(bookings.filter(function(item){
        return item.data().watched == false;
      }))
    }
    setWatched(previousState => !previousState);
  }

  const updateBooking = async(id) => {
    try {
      await setDoc(doc(db, 'booking', id), {
        watched: true
      }, {merge: true})
    }
    catch(e) {
      console.log(e)
    }
  }

  const updateBooking1 = async(id) => {
    try {
      await setDoc(doc(db, 'booking', id), {
        watched: false
      }, {merge: true})
    }
    catch(e) {
      console.log(e)
    }
  }

  const deleteBooking = async(id) => {
    try {
      await deleteDoc(doc(db, 'booking', id));
    }
    catch(e) {
      console.log(e)
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const resultOfFiltering = bookings
    setFilteredBookings(resultOfFiltering)
  }, [bookings])

  return (
    <View>
      <View>
        <Text>{text}</Text>
        <Switch 
          value = {watched}
        />
      </View>
  
  <FlatList
    data = {filteredBookings}

    renderItem  = {({item}) => (
      <View>
      <View>
        <Text>{item.data().movie}</Text>
        <Text>{item.data().day} - {item.data().showtime}</Text>
      </View>
      <View>
        {item.data().watched == true ? (
            <TouchableOpacity style = {styles.delete} onPress = {() => {updateBookings(item.id); setFilteredBookings();}}>
            <Image source={require('../assets/watched.png')}/>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        ) : (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress = {() => {updateBookings1(item.id); setFilteredBookings();}}>
        <Image source={require('../assets/towatch.png')}/>
        </TouchableOpacity>)}

        <TouchableOpacity onPress = {() => {deleteBooking(item.id); setFilteredBookings();}}>
          <Image source={require('../assets/remove.png')}/>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      </View>
    )}
  />
      </View>
  )
}

export default WatchList
```

It's not really working properly at the moment and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong so I'm kind of stuck. If I could get some help, I'd really appreciate it. Thank you!

Comment: hey @Mihailo, FlatList is a pure component you need to paas the variable watched in its extraData Props for it to rerender eg extraData={watched}

Comment: Thank you! I can see that the value of the booking changes, but I have to click the toggle twice (to change the state and to bring it back to the original state) to see that the FlatList looks different (doesn't contain that booking). How do I change it?